# Is it possible to define a homomorphism from a lattice to a poset?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\textbf{L}=<L, \wedge, \vee>$ and $\textbf{P}=<P, \sim>$. Is it possible to define a homomorphism from $\phi: L$ ->$P$?

I know what a homomorphism is and I know its possible to have homomorphism between 2 lattices. But I'm having doubts one exists between a lattice and a poset. Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can treat the lattice as a poset (which it is in a unique way) and consider monotone functions $L\to P$. Another possibility would be to require that your function is monotone and that it preserves meets and/or joins conditionally to their existence in $P$. There are generally no canonical answers. Things depend on what you want to do with your lattice and poset.